# Automorphism in splitting field

Tags: ring-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Suppose $F\subseteq L$ is any field extension, $f(x) \in F[x]$ and $\beta_1,\beta_2,....\beta_r\in L$ are distinct roots of $f(x)$. Prove

a)If $\sigma$ is an automorphism of L that leaves F fixed pointwise, then $\sigma|_{\{\beta_1,...,\beta_r\}}$ is a permutation of $\{\beta_1,....,\beta_r\}$

b)$\sigma \mapsto \sigma|_{\{\beta_1,.....,\beta_r\}}  $ is a homomorphism of $Aut_F(L)$ into the group of permutation $Sym(\{\beta_1,...,\beta_r\})$

c) If L is a splitting field of $f(x)$,     $L=K(\beta_1,...., \beta_r)$, then the homomorphism $\sigma \mapsto \sigma |_{\{\beta_1,....\beta_r\}}$ is injective.
Please help me understand.

My attempt: for a)Assume f(x) is irreducible in F[x].  $\sigma $ is an automorphism of L and $\beta_i$ is a root of $f(x)$ $F\subset F(\beta_1)\subset F(\beta_1,\beta_2)\subset .....\subset F(\beta_1,...,\beta_r)=L$. Hence $\sigma (\beta_i)\mapsto \beta_j$ and they are all distinct. That is $\sigma |_{\{\beta_1,...\beta_r\}}$ is a permutation of the roots.

For b, Let $\tau : Aut_F(L)\rightarrow Sym(\{\beta_1,...,\beta_r\})$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$\sigma \mapsto \sigma|_{\{\beta_1,...,\beta_r\}}$

That is $\tau (\sigma)=\sigma|_{\{\beta_1,...\beta_r\}}$ but I do not know how to do further.

Comment: For ${\bf c.}$, isn't the field $L$ equal to $F(\beta_1,...,\beta_r)$? Not $K(\beta_1,...,\beta_r)$

Comment: I typed it right. It is K, not F. It said  $L = K (\beta1,...,\beta_r)$ . That is what I do not know what is K is. http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/algebrabook.dir/book.2.6.pdf page 342, problem 7.4.5

Comment: It must be a typo. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SplittingField.html. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Abstract_Algebra/Splitting_Fields_and_Algebraic_Closues

Comment: @DanielEscudero I don't think it is a typo. Since L is extension field of F, but L is not splitting field of f(x) yet. For part c), they defined $K(\beta-1,...,\beta_r)$ is splitting field of f(x) to show that K contains only roots of f(x) and f(x) itself. In other words, K is the smallest extension field of f(x)

Comment: You're wrong. $L$ was nothing special until item $c$. In that part, they consider... "and what if you are in the special case that $L$ is the splitting field of $F$? How do the previous result look here?". The splitting field of a polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ is the smallest extension field of $F$ that contains the roots $\beta_1,...\beta_r$ of $f(x)$. It can be easily seen that this field is $F(\beta_1,...\beta_r)$ (you can try to prove it by your own).

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** For **a.**, prove that $\sigma(\beta_i)$ must be a root of $f(x)$ for all $i$, thus $\sigma(\beta_i)=\beta_j$, since $\sigma$ is bijective $\cdots$. This (almost) immediately implies **b.**

For **c.** Prove that any automorphism of $F(\beta_1,...,\beta_r)$ that fixes $F$ is completely determined by its values on $\beta_1,...\beta_r$.